# I'm learning Camunda . How to save a process XML document into act_ge_bytearray without deploying?

Tags: camunda

I want to save my process definition. But so far, I only know that my process files will be saved when deploying.

But I just want to save without deploying.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Especially when you are learning: Stick to the API!

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is not fully clear. If you just want to save the file without deploying it, then you can save it to the location of your choice in the Desktop Modeler or download it from the web modeler, both without deploying it.
There is no need to store this file in the Camunda runtime if you do not want to deploy and use it. Feel feel to store it e.g. in Git.
You should not write something to Camunda tables directly, circumventing the API, as Jan already pointed out.

You can use the Camunda Web Modeler to manage and store process models and other artifacts without deploying them. For Camunda 7 you can use Cawemo.com. for Camunda 8 you can use the Saas version of the web modeler available under camunda.io, or a beta version of the web modeler for self-managed installation (https://docs.camunda.io/docs/self-managed/web-modeler/installation/).

Answer (score 1):

It is just an xml file ... just save it wherever you want. Typically, it will be stored in a git repository because the model is versioned part of your codebase.

Comment: I don't know whether camunda provides this function. But you are right. I can store the process design in my customized table in the database,  such as MySql .